# Window 10 installation on dell vostro 3670

Tags: dell-vostro

I installed Window 10 with a bootable USD drive on a dell vostro 3670, it appeared to install successfully but when I removed the USB drive and restarted the system it would not boot from the HDD. Then I insert the USB drive again it successfully booted from the HDD into Window 10. Is it necessary to insert the USB drive every time I want to boot up the computer?

Comment: It should not be required.  It sounds like Windows was not properly installed.  I would install it again, making sure you delete all partitions on the HDD, doing that will ensure Windows is installed correctly.

Comment: we install about 5 to 6 times but same problem i also installed window 8 and server 2012 but occured same problem. Where as tis problem not occurred on dell vostro 3668 but 3670 give same problem. we all are shockked y it gives pr9blm

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.  Submit a screenshot of your disk within Disk Mangement.  It will help verify you have the required partitions to actually boot your machine.  All improvements to your question should be in the form of an edit to your question instead of a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem a while...
First, you didn't mention if your HDD is GPT or MBR style!

If it is GPT then you need to format your USB as FAT32 and use a tool like [RUFUS](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.6/rufus-3.6.exe) and follow this img:

[image]

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas
I had the exact same problem,
He might have installed from USB not prepared as GPT, like me, I had to put the USB every time to start Windows or else Windows cannot start and the problem got solved when I installed Windows this way..